# How to get half of the full window using grid.row in xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to get a structure like this:
[image]

So i tried this:

```
<!-- Canvas -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--Toolbox & poperties -->

            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
                <Button Content="sdf"/>

            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                <Button Content="sdf"/>


            </StackPanel>
            </Grid>


    </Grid>
```

But I couldn't get the half of the height using grid. What else I could do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following markup and use `Grid.RowSpan` to extend `StackPanel` into two rows

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>

     <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="sdf"/>
     <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="sdf"/>
     <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
</Grid>
```